# GNU Global - cannot find C++ member definitions

Tags: c++, emacs, gnu-global

I'm using GNU Global with a C++ project in Emacs and want to find the definition of a class member starting from any use of that member within a member function.

Example for illustration:

```
class Foo                  // Foo.h
{
    int doSomething();
    int bar;
};

int Foo::doSomething()     // Foo.cpp
{
    return bar;
}

class Foo1                // Foo1.h 
{
    int bar(int b);
};

int Foo1::bar(int b)
{
    return b+1;
}

class Foo2                // Foo2.h
{
    int bar(int b);
};

int Foo2::bar(int b)
{
    return b+1;
}
```

I have set the environment variable GTAGSFORCECPP for C++ support.
After running gtags (without any parameters), I want to see all definitions of the name "bar" by using `global -d --result=grep bar` (The `-d` actually doesn't make a difference). The result is

```
Foo1.h:6:int Foo1::bar(int b)
Foo2.h:6:int Foo2::bar(int b)
```

which is missing the definition of the member `Foo::bar`. On the other hand, if i search for references via `global -r --result=grep bar`, the outcome is

```
Foo.cpp:3:    return bar;
Foo.h:4:    int bar;
Foo1.h:3:    int bar(int b);
Foo2.h:3:    int bar(int b);
```

How must Global be configured so that `int bar;` gets classified as a definition and not as a reference?

So this is kind of the theory part. In practice, I'm using Global from within Emacs and want to find the definition of bar, when hitting `M-.` on `return bar;`. Emacs calls `global -v --result=grep --color=always --path-style=shorter --from-here=3:Foo.cpp -- bar`
which outputs the same as `global -d --result=grep bar`.
I have also tried different parsers (exuberant-ctags, pygments) by setting GTAGSLABEL, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be avoided by using the plug-in parser `exuberant-ctags` **and** not setting GTAGSFORCECPP (as it is said [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/globaldoc_toc.html)). Then, `global -d --result=grep bar` contains the definition of Foo::bar :

```
Foo.h:4:int bar;
Foo1.h:6:int Foo1::bar(int b)
Foo2.h:6:int Foo2::bar(int b)
```